# Access parent object data member from sub-object in Python

Tags: python, decorator, composition

I have a setup like the following

```
class decorator:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    @staticmethod
    def wrap(fn):
        return decorator(fn)

    def __call__(self):
        print(f"decorator {self} function called")


class A:
    @decorator.wrap
    def foo(self):
        print(f"Object {self} called")

    def __init__(self):
        self.boo = 'Boo'
```

How do I from the decorator object access `boo` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@S.B's solution works but is not thread-safe since multiple instances of `A` may be calling the `foo` method at about the same time in different threads, overriding the decorator object's `instance` attribute before a call to the `__call__` method originated from another instance is made.

A thread-safe approach would be to return a wrapper function from the `__get__` method with the instance available through closure:

```
class decorator:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f'decorator {self} function called; boo = {instance.boo}')
            return self.fn(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

class A:
    @decorator
    def foo(self):
        print(f"Object {self} called")

    def __init__(self):
        self.boo = 'Boo'

A().foo()
```

This outputs:

```
decorator <__main__.decorator object at 0x7f6ef3316c10> function called; boo = Boo
Object <__main__.A object at 0x7f6ef3339580> called
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBTsMwEEX3PsWom9hRlA0bBKpEOQAcIXKdcQlEM5btKkJVzx5i3KQhYlb22H/m/e@@4wfTw6Pz42h6HQK0aNjryP5JwFQtWmiajrrYNDJgbyuwpPJbqtSqLcF@aouV4oR3QUchajJYAQ@Efv/GhKsRSTB47Rx6WWp/ChWU5deQTqtfqZzvKEpbLIxwSRuuYM9kYscERvc9ts9wZJ6QLvPmerpfC/VnmMd49jQbkHfILYPYKG6sQuTADpnxZYFaUrDMvwmsXNwc7N6Pn2jijJ@pd0r8H/k27myueGUuhDhIVadFahx/AA)

Comment: +1 Way better. Not only it was not thread safe, even in single thread it causes problems(storing `m = obj.foo` and then calling something else and then `m()`). I deleted mine as it doesn't make sense anymore.